# Efficient way for python date string manipulation

Tags: python, string, date

I want to turn '07/18/2013' to '07/2013' and there are a lot of these strings to be processed. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

I am thinking of using

```
''.join(['07/18/2013'[0:3],'07/18/2013'[6:]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into strftime and strptime.

Assuming you start with the string *s* you can put it into a datetime object using strptime then take that back out into a string with only the necessary fields using strftime.  I didn't actually run this code so I don't know if it is perfect, but the idea is here.

```
temp = datetime.strptime.(s, "%m/%D/%Y")
final = temp.strftime(%m/%Y")
```

You can find info on the datetime functions here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime module:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strptime("07/18/2013", '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m/%Y')
```

Comment: This is the quick one line way to do this which is what I would do, but I gave the long drawn out version to hopefully make it clearer.